# The relation of GCD and capacity?

Tags: terminology

I saw some books call GCD(Greatest Common Divisor) capacity.

Why call it this name? or it's just a name without further learning value?

[capacity in wiki, related with measure, however there is no content of "GCD" within it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacity_of_a_set).

one understanding: GCD is some measure of numbers?

Comment: The capacity in your wiki link has nothing to do with GCD. They are entirely unrelated.

Comment: @WillieWong yes, that's why I ask this question, wiki's page has no content of GCD.

Comment: Can you indicate at least one book that calls GCD capacity? It is most likely just a coincidence that two different things are both called capacity by two different (groups of) people.

Comment: try to find a connection eg. through analytic number theory. Make a discovery.